# Javascript library to manage DOM actions and properties

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm looking for a library that will allow me to specify css classes for DOM elements and map them to javascript functions to define events like `onclick`. For example:

```
<form class="auto delete">
    <input type="checkbox" class="auto submit"/>
</form>
```

Then All I would need to write is:

```
function Form_autoDelete(form){
    form.action = '/forms/delete_stuff/';
    form.method = 'post';
    form.onsubmit = function () { alert('thanks!'); }
}
```

and

```
function Checkbox_autoSubmit(form,checkbox){
    checkbox.onclick = function(isChecked){
                           form.submit();
                        }
}
```

Then when someone checks the box (or unchecks it), the form will automatically submit to `/forms/delete_stuff/` without me actually having to write anything in the html but the css classes. If this exists, I couldn't figure out what to search for to find it.

Is there already an existing library like this?

Comment: Use jQuery class selectors and [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach an event handler to certain css classes.

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, this is the kind of thing you do with MVC frameworks.

Comment: @Danny, that would work, but it's not quite what I'm looking for. Barmar, I didn't think to look at MVCs (though I should've). I'll look at some and see if I find anything.

Comment: wouldn't this be `software tools commonly used by programmers` (if you count libraries as tools) and `a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development`? Therefore **NOT** off topic.

Comment: @Barmar, from perusing a few MVCs code samples, most of them use a different language (or additional tags) to define things in the HTML or they operate in strings like with JQuery (`$('.someClass').first().on('click',func)`), among various other minor complaints. They'd work, but what I'm proposing seems simpler and requires almost no learning beyond basic javascript/html. It also encapsulates functionality very cleanly IMO.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want if it's not an MVC framework and it's not just how to use a library like jQuery to bind handlers. I don't think there's anything in between.

Comment: @Barmar, See my answer. That is what I wanted. I was hoping there was a library with a little more functionality or other improvements, but I'm happy with what I have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the answer is probably **no**, so I wrote my own.
Get up to date code and documentation from github: https://github.com/JakarCo/javascript-dom

The code that I wrote to make the snippet work is the `jdomA_link(parent,a)` function and the two css classes in the `a` tag. Overall, pretty simple to use, I think.

Notice the only code on the `<a>` tag is the two css classes and the rest is handled by JS. Note that you can do whatever you want with the HTML. I used the JS-only solution here for example.

```js
function jdomA_link(parent,a){
    a.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com';
    a.style.backgroundColor = '#0F0';
    var counter = 0;
    a.onclick = function(){
      a.innerText = 'you clicked me '+(++counter)+' times';
      a.style.backgroundColor = '#0FF';
    }
}

/*
* Make sure to either include this code AFTER all your jdom functions
* or remove `JDOMProcessor.pageLoaded();` from the bottom of this file 
* and put it somewhere you KNOW it will be loaded after your jdom functions
*
* I can't, at this time, guarantee execution order of your jdom functions
*/

/** I'm enclosing so that function names don't conflict with user's functions
*
*/
var JDOMProcessor = {
 /**returns string with first char capital and the rest lower case
 */
 capitaliseFirstLetter : function(string)
 {
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1).toLowerCase();
 },
 /**returns class list without the jdom class
 */
 classList : function(element){
  var classList = element.className;
  var array = classList.split(" ");
  for(var i = 0; i <array.length; i++) {
   if(array[i] == 'jdom') {
      array.splice(i, 1);
   }
  }
  return array;
 },
 /** the page has finished loading. This maps everything
 */
 pageLoaded: function(logFuncNames){
   logFuncNames = logFuncNames || false;
  var elementList = document.getElementsByClassName('jdom'); 
  for (var i = 0;i<elementList.length;i++){
   var element = elementList[i];
   var classList = this.classList(element);
   var parent = element.parentNode;
   var classListString = classList.join('_');
   var parentName = this.capitaliseFirstLetter(parent.tagName);
   var elementName = this.capitaliseFirstLetter(element.tagName);
   var didFunc = false;
   var tagIndex = 0;
   var classes = classList.length;
   while (!didFunc&&classes>0){
    var tagNames = [parentName,elementName,'' ];
    var funcName = 'jdom'+tagNames.slice(tagIndex).join('')+"_"+classList.slice(0,classes).join("_");
    
    var func = window[funcName];
    if (func!=null){
     func(parent,element);
     didFunc = true; 
    }
    
    if (++tagIndex>tagNames.length){
     classes = --classes;
     tagIndex = 0;
    }
    if (logFuncNames)console.log(funcName);
   }
  }
 }
}
//you can remove this call from the file and place it somewhere on your own if you'd like.
JDOMProcessor.pageLoaded();
```

```html
<a class="jdom link">link text</a>
```